# Create a custom list of Orders in NopCommerce

Tags: asp.net-mvc, list, e-commerce, nopcommerce, orders

I'm trying to create a list of orders in a custom Controller in a NopCommerce/MVC application and i want the list to be sorted by creationDate and contain total orders for that date and convert these values to string format.

The thing is i **don't** want an ActionResult displaying a grid in the view like in Admin/Orders. All i want is a List of all paid orders between model.StartDate and model.EndDate that contains two parameters "CreationDateUtc" and TotalOrders". i simply just need a list containing the data of orders sorted by creationdate.

The if i choose StartDate 2014-03-29 and EndDate 2014-04-02 the output i want would look something like this:

**List OrdersTotalList with parameters CreationDateUtc and TotalOrders**

```
CreationDateUtc "2014-03-29" 
TotalOrders "562"

CreationDateUtc "2014-03-30" 
TotalOrders "485"

CreationDateUtc "2014-03-31" 
TotalOrders "733"

CreationDateUtc "2014-04-01" 
TotalOrders "729"

CreationDateUtc "2014-04-02" 
TotalOrders "681
```

"

**I'm trying to access the data by an implementations of OrderList from OrderController in my CustomController. Problem is this method always returns 10 objects when infact the total number of orders within this timespace is 58. When debugging Total = orders.TotalCount are actually showing 58 orders as one int value). Also a gridmodel is used here but i really don't need a gridmodel, i just need the data from the database:**

public List OrderList(GridCommand command, OrderListModel model, OrderModel Omodel)
            {

```
            DateTime S = new DateTime(2014, 3, 29); //-- Dates for testing
            DateTime E = new DateTime(2014, 4, 02);

            model.StartDate = S;
            model.EndDate = E;

            DateTime? startDateValue = (model.StartDate == null) ? null
                            : (DateTime?)_dateTimeHelper.ConvertToUtcTime(model.StartDate.Value, _dateTimeHelper.CurrentTimeZone);

            DateTime? endDateValue = (model.EndDate == null) ? null
                            : (DateTime?)_dateTimeHelper.ConvertToUtcTime(model.EndDate.Value, _dateTimeHelper.CurrentTimeZone).AddDays(1);

            OrderStatus? orderStatus = model.OrderStatusId > 0 ? (OrderStatus?)(model.OrderStatusId) : null;
            PaymentStatus? paymentStatus = model.PaymentStatusId > 0 ? (PaymentStatus?)(model.PaymentStatusId) : null;
            ShippingStatus? shippingStatus = model.ShippingStatusId > 0 ? (ShippingStatus?)(model.ShippingStatusId) : null;

            //load orders
            var orders = _orderService.SearchOrders(startDateValue, endDateValue, orderStatus,
                paymentStatus, shippingStatus, model.CustomerEmail, model.OrderGuid, command.Page - 1, command.PageSize);
            var gridModel = new GridModel<OrderModel>
            {
                Data = orders.Select(x =>
                {
                    var customerCurrency = _currencyService.GetCurrencyByCode(x.CustomerCurrencyCode);
                    var totalInCustomerCurrency = _currencyService.ConvertCurrency(x.OrderTotal, x.CurrencyRate);

                    return new OrderModel()
                    {
                        Id = x.Id,
                        OrderTotal = _priceFormatter.FormatPrice(totalInCustomerCurrency, true, customerCurrency),
                        OrderStatus = x.OrderStatus.GetLocalizedEnum(_localizationService, _workContext),
                        PaymentStatus = x.PaymentStatus.GetLocalizedEnum(_localizationService, _workContext),
                        ShippingStatus = x.ShippingStatus.GetLocalizedEnum(_localizationService, _workContext),

                        CreatedOn = _dateTimeHelper.ConvertToUserTime(x.CreatedOnUtc, DateTimeKind.Utc)
                    };
                }),


                Total = orders.TotalCount <-- Returns all orders (58) but as an integer


            };



            var reportSummary = _orderReportService.GetOrderAverageReportLine
             (orderStatus, paymentStatus, shippingStatus, startDateValue, endDateValue, model.CustomerEmail);
            var profit = _orderReportService.ProfitReport
                (orderStatus, paymentStatus, shippingStatus, startDateValue, endDateValue, model.CustomerEmail);
            var aggregator = new OrderModel()
            {
                aggregatorprofit = _priceFormatter.FormatPrice(profit, true, false),
                aggregatortax = _priceFormatter.FormatPrice(reportSummary.SumTax, true, false),
                aggregatortotal = _priceFormatter.FormatPrice(reportSummary.SumOrders, true, false)
                //aggregatordates = 
            };

            List<Order> TotalProductsSold = new List<Order>();

        foreach (var o in orders)
        {

            TotalProductsSold.Add(o);


        }


            return TotalProductsSold.ToList(); //<-- returns 10 orders containing all order info
        }
```

If i understand correct in order to archive this i have to first search through orders and if their PaymentStatus is Paid. Then create a List in the Method from above. A foreach loop could iterate through orders and add orders to the List, all though i need to specify i only want CreationDate and TotalOrders for that date as parameters in the List.

**I know this isn't right but i emagine something similar. The thing is i need a list of order objects and not one object with one value:**

```
List<OrderModel> OrdersTotalList = new List<OrderModel>();

    foreach (var o in orders)
                {

                    OrderModel OM = new OrderModel(OM.OrderTotal, OM.CreatedOn);

                    OrdersTotalList.Add(OM);

                }

    return OrdersTotalList; //--
```

Am i completely of or is this the right aproach? I was hoping someone more familiar with NopCommerce knows more about this.

Sorry for all the text

Thank you

Comment: Your question is a little hard to follow. Your throwing out terms specific to just this project that we don't know. Can you condense your question?

Comment: I'm sorry i will update the post and write more in terms of code than platform/project.

Comment: Please check page size of ur Telerik grid, it must be set to 10 in the view

Comment: Thx Nitin. Well might be the problem but the thing is i don't want to display the data in a view. All i want is to create a list with two parameters. 1 for total orders by date and 2 for the actual date (CreatedOnUtc). It must be an easy way getting this data from the database? Like 2014-02-05 - 200 orders, 2014-04-06 - 230 orders etc.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

In order to get a full list of orders you can create a new constructor in IOrderService/OrderService that is of type List instead of IPagedList. The method used for searching orders are called "SearchOrders" and is of type IPagedList. IPagedList contains the property PageSize wich results in only 10 orders.

You can create a new method with same implementation as SearchOrders and change IPagedList to List, remove "int pageIndex" and "int pageSize".

Then use:

```
            _orderService.YourNewConstructor(DateTime? startTime, DateTime? endTime,
            OrderStatus? os, PaymentStatus? ps, ShippingStatus? ss, string billingEmail,
            string orderGuid)
            {
                 some code...
            }
```

This will give you access to all orders.